# How to apply CSS to table cell depending on conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with 10 rows and data is

```
ABC XYZ 30% (ABC)
ABC MNO 91% (XYZ)



var table = document.getElementById("table2");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
   var data = col.innerText;
   var data1 = data.split(" ");
   if(data1[0] == "91%"){
        row.cells[j].css( "color", "red" );
   }
   }  
}
```

I want to add red color to the cells which are above 90%. How to do it.
I know in back-end we can do it but now I am using only html and CSS.

Comment: `row.cells[j].css( "color", "red" );` ==> `row.cells[j].style.color = 'red';` jQuery ruined you. Also, look at `for` too. no condition.

Comment: is there any way to do it for background color. and also can check for no like > 90% no not to stringwith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight variation in your code can make it works

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table2");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    var data = col.innerText;
    // replace % symbol, parse and compare with number
    if (+data.replace('%', '') > 90) {
      // update style property of cell
      col.style.color = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>30%</td>
    <td>(ABC)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>MNO</td>
    <td>91%</td>
    <td>(XYZ)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If a single column contains the entire string then do something like this

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table2");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    // get the percentage value from string
    var data = col.innerText.match(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%/);
    // check match found or not then parse and compare with number
    if (data && +data[1] > 90) {
      // update style property of cell
      col.style.color = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>ABC XYZ 30% (ABC)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC MNO 91% (XYZ)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```